# Perl: What does <*> do?

Tags: perl

I ran into this subroutine:

```
241 sub update_file {
242     my $old = shift;
243     my $new = shift;
244
245     my   @old = <$old*>;                        <----------
246
247     if (scalar(@old) == 0) {
...
```

I goolged perl <*> but I wasn't able to find it anywhere.
What does <*> do?

Comment: [Googling for special characters is useless](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en). Use Perl's built-in documentation: `perldoc perlvar` and `perldoc perlop` are good places to start. It's a bit of a slog, but even if I search for `<` in `perlop`, I eventually get to `<>` in the section "I/O Operators".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<$old*>` is the same as [`glob(qq<$old*>)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) which can also be written as `glob("$old*")`.

If `$old` is something like

```
/foo/some\ dir/
```

it will list return the files in

```
/foo/some dir
```

except those that start with `.`.

Comment: Or if `$old` is `/etc/default/a` it would return a list of all files and subdirectories whose name begins with `a` in `/etc/default`.